# Go to the specific chapter in PDF, iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

I'm having quite a problem with viewing PDF in iOS. I want to be able to list user all chapters of a file and after he clicks one of them show this chapter directly in the view.

I now that I can get all chapters by:

```
PDFDocument* pdfDoc = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:... ];
PDFOutline* pdfOutline = [pdfDoc outlineRoot];
```

For now I was using webView, I was even able to write my own `goToPage` method but don't know how to do this feature. Maybe there is library I can use for this purpose or I can get information from `PDFOutline` object (I haven't found anything useful in documentation)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think you're stuck because you're very close to what you want to do. You can check how many outline items there are and get all of them:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfChildren
```

returns the number of outline items and

```
- (PDFOutline *)childAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

can be used to retrieve each item.

Once you have such an item, you can get its destination:

```
- (PDFDestination *)destination
```

If you read the documentation and the PDF specification, you'll see that an outline item can either have a destination or an action that specifies what needs to happen when it is executed (clicked).

You'll have to interpret what the destination means and use your gotoPage function to go to the correct page (PDFDestination has a "page" member that tells you exactly what page it refers to).